# How to get the static property in non static method - typescript

Tags: typescript, es6-class

I have similar classes as in the following code.

```
class Base {
  protected abstract static link: string;

  public fetch(){
    // Solution need
    const link =  self.link;

    // Do other things with link
  }
}

class A extends Base {
  protected static link = 'some link'
}

class B extends Base {
 protected static link = 'other link'
}
```

And I need to define a common function to fetch data for each model based on the link value. 
I can not change the static `link` value to a property. Because of some static methods using this link value.

I have tried with `Base.link`. But I can not access the original value of child class with this method. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Base {
  protected static link: string;

  public fetch(){
    const self = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor;
    return self.link
  }
}

class A extends Base {
  static link = 'some link'
}

class B extends Base {
  static link = 'other link'
}

const b = new B();
const a = new A();
console.log(b.fetch()) // other link
console.log(a.fetch()) // some link
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kwsejh